# Using a video as the background of an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, video

im new to the iPhone SDK and development. I work for a company that is looking to create some proof-of-concept iPhone applications and one of the requests/potential features was using a video file as the background for the application.

I understand that from a user experience pov this isnt necaserrily classed as best practice however if I can at least prove that this can be done whilst also listing the pro's and con's of doing so this would benefit me greatly.

Any help on this subject is greatly appreciated :)

Regards,

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement this through Quartz Core using layers (see the CALayer class documentation). Indeed, you can have layers hierarchies.

However, you should carefully, as already stated, take into account the heavy load. For just a few seconds, it may be acceptable though.

Basically you associate each UIView to a different layer, then the layers are rendered together providing a single, composite layer. Besides, you can also apply transforms and animations to layers.

You need to import the QuartzCore header and do something like

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame...
UIView *myMoviewView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame...

CaLayer *myViewLayer = myView.layer;
[myViewLayer addSubLayer: myMoviewView];
```

Then, when myView appears on the screen, all the sublayers are merged together and rendered on screen. What happens is that each view renders its layer, while myViewLayer is rendered merging together the two layers.

You can have as many layers as you like. You can create an arbitrary hierarchy by using the CALayer methods

```
– addSublayer: – removeFromSuperlayer
– insertSublayer:atIndex:
– insertSublayer:below:
– insertSublayer:above:
– replaceSublayer:with:
```

Comment: Excellent response, thanks very much for taking the time to explain this to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible, but a major con would be the heavy load to the iPhone's CPU, available RAM, and battery level in doing this.

Comment: I realise this and I have voiced my concerns - this is meant to be a usability app rather than something of eye candy however they still are asking me to prove it either way. Ive read a through articles on animated backgrounds but so far nothing as far as video is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if someone is still needing it, but I would definitely go for a fullscreen UIWebView with autolayout and having videos as background of the web page.
At least you can play with mediaquery and load the proper video according to the iPhone model and viewport and I guess it is much easier to achieve a fullscreen video with CSS3 than with Obj-C in this case...